# Using X-Frame-Options to prevent ClickJacking

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I have been trying to implement this on my website, but haven't been able to find the right way to do it.
My Apache/PHP website has an `/includes/` folder with a few basic javascripts. Qualys is reporting these as vulnerable to "ClickJacking".
As per OWASP's instructions, I have tried using `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`. 
With that said, I went to the .htaccess of that `/includes/` folder and added the following:

```
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
```

However, this has disabled all those javascripts on the website, so I had to revert back.
Can somebody help me implement this properly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That header should be applied to your HTML documents, not your script files. It shouldn't have any effect on your script files. Most likely, you are getting a 500 error when you try to load the scripts. Read the error logs for your server to find out what the problem actually is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The guide says to apply that to my Apache configuration or .htaccess file. The website doesn't have any HTML files. I will check the logs and see what I can find.

Comment: If you don't have any HTML then what are people supposed to click on which might get clickjacked?

Comment: That is a good question. This is a PHP website. I didn't know people could use clickjacking on a PHP website with a few simple javascripts.

Comment: Does the PHP generate HTML?

Comment: No. It doesn't.

Comment: So there's still nothing that could be clicked, so there's still nothing that could be jacked.

Comment: Exactly. That is what I told Qualys and they still won't accept that.

Comment: So ask them for a proof of concept attack demo.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the advise.